# Elite Four members don't give correct reward money with Amulet Coin?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I've been playing Pokemon Ruby as of late, and once I got past Victory Road, I noticed I was extremely low on money for potions and whatnot, so I looked around for ways to farm some.

I read on GameFAQs that defeating the Elite Four members repeatedly with the Amulet Coin was a viable way to earn some quick money, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

![Images of my Pokemon game before and after defeating an Elite Four member.][1]

The image above shows before, after defeating the Elite Four member (with the Amulet Coin), and after entirely. (After step 3 below.) The pictures were actually taken after the first attempt at this. I dumped my money on some potions and tried again, just to make sure it wasn't a fluke.

This is my method:

1. Start battle with the first Elite Four member.
2. Defeat him.
3. Go on to the second member, get as far as I can until I die.
4. I die because I'm actually terribly under-leveled for how far I am in the game, so I'm getting EXP and money at the same time. Groudon is slightly higher than the rest due to being captured at level 45 and being used for the EXP Share.

After defeating the first Elite Four member, I'm only actually making $2367, not the $4900 it says I'm making...This is odd, as

1. I'm using the Amulet Coin.
2. $2367 != $2450 (What would be the normal reward money without the Amulet Coin.)

Does anyone know why this is happening? My only guess would be because I intentionally die on the second Elite Four member, thus it messes up the Amulet Coin because I can't leave once it's started. Is that the case?

**--EDIT--**

I was unaware that the Amulet Coin was supposed to be given to a Pokemon to hold! That being said:

1. Base reward money from this member is $4900.
2. With coin: $9800.
3. Upon death, I'm left with about half of what I had -> $4952 (I started with $105)

Is it normal to lose half of your money upon blacking out? I've never actually checked before.

Comment: Did you check your cash amount after step 2?  That might help figure out where the problem is being caused.

Comment: @Frank - I have not, sir. Allow me to do so quickly. I'll report back.

Comment: Alrighty. Dumped my money again, was left with $110. Repeated step 2, and yes, I am getting the entire $4900 once he is defeated for a total of $5010.

Comment: Ok, so now we have a cash total at step 2.  Let's continue onto step 3, and check again.

Comment: Done. I made my way into the second member's room and checked. Still A-OK with $5010. Took the dive to her, was teleported outside after death. Checked, $2505 - Half of what I had before.

Comment: Hmm.  We can't reproduce your problem.  Are you sure you've replicated the steps exactly?  I don't know of any moves that provide cash beyond Payday.  Unless you have that, sounds like a fluke or something.

Comment: @Frank, please see the edit I made to the original post. I added some extra information that may help.

Comment: Since you came to an answer on your own, you should write an answer to your own question and mark it as "correct" so its not sitting as an open question.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you are dying after you defeat the first member of the elite four, which halves your total money. Since you weren't checking your money between defeating the first member and losing to the second member, it appeared that you were getting half as much money as you really were, since you immediately lose half of all the money you get.

Answer (score 1):

OP's answer from the question:

---

[According to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Black_out#Formula_for_money_lost) - "Before Generation IV, half of the money on hand was lost and this loss was not explicitly stated to the player."

A little bit of research goes a long way. I didn't quite know what to look up before asking this question, and what I did look up returned nothing useful. But that link provides quite a lot of useful information indeed!

Thanks @Frank for helping me along the way!